# Limit the activated image in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing the CMS.. How should I able to limit the activated images with message? For example I would like to limit 5 activated image and I also would like to put some message if he exceed to the limit like "Only 5 activated images only!"

I already tried this but the message wont display(I also checked the $result).. Is there something wrong in my codes? What is it?

**View**

```
@extends('dashboard')
@section('content')


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Upload New Image</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="titleLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header modal-header-success">
        <button type="button" class="close btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="titleLabel">New Image</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="text-content">
              <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-5">
                <br>
                @if($errors->first('image'))
                <p class="errors">
                  <div class = "alert alert-danger">  
                    <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                    <ul>
                      {!!$errors->first('image')!!}
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </p>
                @endif

                 @if ($message = Session::get('failed'))
                <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                  <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </div>
                @endif
                <h4>Choose to Upload:</h4>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                  <form action="{{ url('file-upload') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="file" class = "filestyle"name="image" />
                      </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <span class="pull-right">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload File</button>
        </span>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
 @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
                <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                  <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </div>
                @endif
<div class="x_content">
  <table class="table table-hover">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach($data as $image)
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ $image->id }}</th>
        <td><img src="/assets/img/{{$image->img_jumbotron}}" width ="50px"> </td>
        <td> 
        @if($image->status=="Activated")
        <form action="/deactivateImage/{{  $image->id}}" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Deactivate</button>
        </form>
        @else
        <form action="{{ url('activateImage', ['id' => $image->id]) }}" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Activate</button>
        </form>
        </td>
        @endif
        <td>{{$image->status}}</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
@stop
```

**Controller**

```
 public function activateImage($id)
    {   
        $result = jumbotron::where(['status' => 'Activated'])->count();
        if($result > 5)
        {
            return back()->with('failed', 'Only 5 images can be activated!');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "not yet";die;
        }

        return back()->with('activated','Image Activated successfully.');

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return [`redirect()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#redirects):

```
return redirect()->back()->with('failed', 'Only 5 images can be activated!');
```

Comment: Sir, what is the difference between the two?

Comment: @Angel from docs: redirect responses are instances of the `Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse` class, and contain the proper headers needed to redirect the user to another URL.